# MySQL/Java error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Newbie programmer here. Upon doing mvn tomcat:run I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL  syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values (?, ?)' at line 1
```

The code in question is as follows:

```
public void create(User user) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password values (?, ?)");


            user.getUserName(); user.getId();

}

public void delete(User user) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM xyz.user WHERE id = ?");


}

public void update(User user) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
            "UPDATE xyz.user SET UserName = ? password = ? WHERE id = ?");
```

Googled - couldn't find a solution for (?, ?) scenarios. Pls. help - Thx in advance :)

Here's the complete code (almost) - I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

```
public User find(String login) {
  System.out.println("Trying to find the user...." + login);    
  User user = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "select * from xyz where user_name = ?",
        new Object[]{login},
        new RowMapper<User>() {
            public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(Long.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)));
                user.setUserName(rs.getString(2));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString(3));
                return user;
            }
        });
  System.out.println("Found user..." + user);
   return user;
}

public void create(User user) {

    this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO ibstechc_dev.user(user_name, user_password) VALUES (?,?)");

            user.getUserName(); user.getId() ;
}


public void delete(User user) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM xyz WHERE id = ?");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void update(User user) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
            "UPDATE xyz SET user_name = ?, user_password = ? WHERE id = ?");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I am stuck with the same error - tomcat:run throws the following -

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
```

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password) values (?, ?)");
```

There was an issue with your SQL statement. To give you perspective you were trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password values ('testuser','testpass'))
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password) values ('testuser','testpass'))
```

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: The parenthesis -it makes sense. Thanks :) But it throws the same error with tomcat:run. I used the suggested code.

Comment: You have to provide the values of username and password to the values statement for this statement to execute correctly. Look at this documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the sql syntax problem:

```
INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password values (?, ?)
```

replace this by

```
INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password) values (?, ?);
```

Answer (score 1):

**There is a sql syntax error in update**

```
public void update(User user) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
            "UPDATE xyz.user SET UserName = ? password = ? WHERE id = ?");
```

this is not the way to update,give a comma(,)  like this

```
public void update(User user) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
            "UPDATE xyz.user SET UserName = ? ,password = ? WHERE id = ?");
```

Comment: @user2480526 you have sql syntax error in insert and update.I have posted only the update part as there already answers for insertion part.You need to change all.

Answer (score 0):

your error is this statement

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password values (?, ?)");
```

It should be

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password) values (?, ?)");
```

Hope it helps

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password) values (?, ?)");
```

instead of

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz.user(user_name, user_password values (?, ?)");
```