# JdbcTemplate, MySQL error

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Need Help! I have asked a question here earlier - [MySQL/Java error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307358/mysql-java-error)      related to this one but not identical (not sure of the protocols at SO for such questions). I am working with JDBC, MySQL and encountering errors. First, the code

```
public User find(String login) {
  System.out.println("Trying to find the user...." + login);    
  User user = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "select * from xyz where user_name = ?",
        new Object[]{login},
        new RowMapper<User>() {
            public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(Long.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)));
                user.setUserName(rs.getString(2));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString(3));
                return user;
            }
        });
  System.out.println("Found user..." + user);
   return user;
}

public void create(User user) {

    this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz (user_name,user_password) VALUES (default, default, ?, ?)",
            new Object[] {user.getUserName(),user.getPassword()});
```

*I need to give default values to user_name, user_password (the 2 columns) but don't know how and where in the "create(User user) block.*

Here's the error for the code above:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I have tried it without 'default', 'default' and just (?, ?) but that gives me yet another error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your  

SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the   

right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column list only has 2 columns, and you're trying to insert 4 values.

```
INSERT INTO xyz (user_name,user_password) VALUES (default, default, ?, ?)
```

Drop the `default` values if the column has a default and is not specified in the column list.

Comment: Thx :) I just edited the question to indicate the errors when I try it without 'default' and just (?, ?).

Comment: The MySQL table does not have default values for these columns.

Comment: @user2480526 You've changed your question at that point. Are your column names really `user_name` and `user_password`? Make sure that your columns are properly escaped if you're using a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Yes. Here's the SQL Stmt. for the table - CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;